# Modelling an S-shaped Second Order Process Response

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, pid-control, optimal-control

I am trying to model an [S-shaped second order process response](https://www.picontrolsolutions.com/papers/step-less-closed-loop-multivariable-transfer-function-system-identification-the-slic-id-algorithm/) as a transfer function in Simulink, as shown in figure 3 in the linked article. Ideally the response should be overdamped. I have tried using the function: $\frac{1}{1s^2+5s+1}$ however my process response is non-S shaped. Could you please give me advise on how to adjust my transfer function such that it emulates the figure in the article?

Comment: Try $1/(s^2 + 2s + 1)$. The `S` shape in the article is exaggerated IMHO.

Comment: diffusion processes make lovely "S" shapes

Comment: Multiply the TF by $e^{-\tau s}$ to implement delay. Perhaps you get a bit closer to an S-shape.